# How to use Kubernetes Persistent Local Volumes with Minikube on OSX?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I want to experiment with [Persistent Local Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local) using Minikube on OSX. I am using the local provisioner (https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner) to create the PVs for me.

I create the local directory on the OSX host and mount it to the Minikube VM:

```
mkdir -p /path/to/data/dir
minikube mount /path/to/data/dir:/data/dir &
```

When I look at the logs for the provisioner, I can see errors like this:

```
Found new volume at host path "/data/dir" with capacity 0, creating Local PV "local-pv-ccc90d9b", required volumeMode "Filesystem"
Error creating PV "local-pv-ccc90d9b" for volume at "/data/zk-2": PersistentVolume "local-pv-ccc90d9b" is invalid: spec.capacity[storage]: Invalid value: "0": must be greater than zero
```

Guided by the advice here (https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/issues/968), I ssh'ed in to the Minikube VM and looked at the capacity of the mount:

```
$ df /data/dir/
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
192.168.99.1           0     0         0    - /data/dir
```

So the capacity of the mount is zero and this seems to the why it's throwing up the error I see.  However, the parent directory

```
$ df /data          
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       16888216 1129408  14769676   8% /data
```

Is this an issue with the `minikube mount` command? Can this be made to work on OSX? How do I get a Persistent Local Volume to work on OSX Minikube?

Comment: Are you sure this should be done under `/data`?[Mounted Host Folders](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/#mounted-host-folders) says its `/Users`

Comment: The static PV provisioner requires that the location that is to be used for each PV must be a mount point; it can't just be a folder.  So you need to have one mount that exists inside the VM for each PV that you want to have created. I don't see anything inside `/Users` inside the VM if I try to mount my directories into there.

Comment: I did not even know I had to mount the data directory myself. I only read at https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/ that several directories including `/data` are allocated to persist data.. But then when I read https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/ it does not mention these as auto mounted for different drivers .

Answer (score 1):

Here is my little how-to for those who ended up on that page looking for a way to share local folders on their Mac with minikube.

Personally, I was spinning up some Azure SQL Edge server (an equivalent to MS SQL Server, but that is compiled for the arm architecture of M1 silicon chips) and I wanted the database's data to persist on my disk so I could restart my pods without loosing their data.

**1. Mount the folder you want to share on your host, in minikube:**

```
minikube mount ./path/to/mySharedData:/mnt1/shared1 --uid 10001 --gid 10001
```

Here, the volume mounted in minikube will have group id and user id 10001. This is the user id of Azure SQL Edge server inside the container.

I used these --uid and --gid arguments because I was running into some write access error.

If you don't know what is the user id inside your container, log into your container and type `id`, it will tell you the user id.

Don't close the terminal. That process needs to be running all the time for the folder to be accessible.

**2. Use that folder with hostPath:**

```
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: mssql-data
          hostPath:
            path: /mnt1/shared1
      containers:
        - name: azuresqledge
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1433
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mssql-data
              mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data
          env:
            - name: MSSQL_PID
              value: "Developer"
            - name: ACCEPT_EULA
              value: "Y"
            - name: SA_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mssql
                  key: SA_PASSWORD
            - name: MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED
              value: "TRUE"
            - name: MSSQL_COLLATION
              value: "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
            - name: MSSQL_LCID
              value: "1033"
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 10001
```

A lot of the stuff here is Azure SQL specific (all the env ...). Two things are important:
Define the volume mounted in minikube with:

```
      volumes:
        - name: mssql-data
          hostPath:
            path: /mnt1/shared1
```

And mount it inside your container where you need:

```
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mssql-data
              mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data
```